# Extracting Phone Number with Call Text from String using Reg exp

Tags: java, regex

Ok Here is my example text... everything is

> THEPONDIS15AWAYLOOKATTHOSEBASS5POUNDERSWELLLITATNIGHTALLAROUNDQUIETSEMICOUNTRYAREASTILLMOREBUT**CALLME**NORENTALNOLEASEANDPLEASEWENEEDNOREALTORSASMYWIFEDOES**3176665440**ANDCANNOTKEEPALLTHEMAINTANCEOFABIGHOUSEWANNAGOSOUTHTHANKSCALLMETHANKS

As you can see the Call and the phone number are within so far of eachother within 60 chars or so.  So I been trying to right an expression to find this, determine that CALL is within 60 chars or so and then pull the phone number if it is..

I know that I would need something like...

```
    Pattern p11 = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{11}");
    Pattern p10 = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{10}");
    Pattern p7 = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{7}");
```

In order to determine if its possibly an actual phone number since it could be **13173333333** or just **3173333333** or just **3333333**

What about the rest?  I know I would probably have to do a type of substring or something, but Its giving me a lot more difficulty then I thought it would.

I tried doing this...

```
        String PHONENUMBER = "";
        Pattern p11 = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{11}");
        Pattern p10 = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{10}");
        Pattern p7 = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{7}");
        Matcher m11 = p11.matcher(Number);
        Matcher m10 = p10.matcher(Number);
        Matcher m7 = p7.matcher(Number);
        String Call = "CALL";
        String Text = "TEXT";
        String Message = "MESSAGE";
        if (Number.contains(Call)) {
            int Numindex = Number.indexOf(Call);
            int low = Numindex - 30;
            int high = Numindex + 35;
            if (low < 0) {
                low = 0;
            }
            if (high > Number.length()) {
                high = Number.length();
            }
            String extract = Number.substring(low, high);
            m11 = p11.matcher(extract);
            m10 = p10.matcher(extract);
            m7 = p7.matcher(extract);
            if (m11.find() == true) {
                PHONENUMBER = m11.group();
            } else if (m10.find() == true) {
                PHONENUMBER = m10.group();
            } else if (m7.find() == true) {
                PHONENUMBER = m7.group();
            }
```

But for some reason its not working out for me

EDIT #1 Requested for Original Text....

The Pond is 15' away- look at those bass- 5 Pounders-- well lit at night all around- quiet Semi Country area...still more but Ca ll me- NO RENTAL/No Lease and Please- we need NO Realtors as my Wife does 317 6 6.6-54.4 0 and cannot keep all the maintance of a big House- wanna go South Thanks call me!Call Me Thanks!

As you can see from the original text, it only makes sense to remove the spaces and all special characters then just do a simple expression comparison to find the phone number, then just find if the word "call" is within 60 chars. Obviously this isn't the ONLY paragraph there are hundreds more.

Comment: Such garbled text is supposed to be parseable? Not that it is impossible but why doesn't your peer send something more... Well.. Parseable to begin with?

Comment: the initial string can have many extra spaces between words/letters or even special characters etc..  so in order to get it to work correctly i already presumed the easiest way would be to remove all the spaces and capitalize everything then determine it from there. Call could be written C A L    L me, or Ca LL me.. etc... phone number could be 343 4  5 6  54 54   etc

Comment: Well, your premise might turn out to be your downfall; please paste the original input instead. Also, you may want to have a look at Google's libphonenumber.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest this seems like you are doing it in an extremely difficult way. However here is an idea on how you could go about doing it.

First get the range you want to check for the number let's say it's 0(low)-15(high)
then write a for loop to loop through that range of characters. The below code is an example of how you could set it up to loop through the section of the string you want checking the characters along the way to see if it matches a phone number. Take in mind this doesn't take in account reaching the end of the String to soon which would result in an index out of bounds exception nor does it take in account if it is too large of a number but I will let you figure those things out.

```
String number = "123HEY1234567890HOWIS";
    int realNum = 0; //if this hits exactly 10 then it is a real phone number
    int low = 0;
    int high = number.length();
    for(int i = low; i < high;i++){
    //check if the current char is a number
    if(number.substring(i, i + 1).matches("[0-9]")){
    //if yes then increment
    realNum++;
    System.out.println(realNum);
      //checks if realNum is 10 and makes sure that the next char isn't a number also
      if(realNum == 10){
      low = i - 9;
      high = i;
      System.out.println("match");
      break;
      }
    }else{
    //if no then reset the checker back to 1
    realNum = 0;
    }
    }
    System.out.println("All Done");
```

Hopefully this at least gets you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I would use https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber and not regex for finding phone numbers. The library works as you would expect

```
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    Iterable<PhoneNumberMatch> numbers = phoneUtil.findNumbers(text, Locale.US.getCountry());
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.forEach(number -> {
        String s = number.rawString();
        // your phone numbers
    });
```